# Algorithm for data rearrangement in a Python dict

Tags: python

In Python, I have the following dict:

```
players = {'player_1': 'data_a',
     'player_2': 'data_b',
     'player_3': 'data_c',
     'player_4': 'data_d',
     'player_5': 'data_e',
     'player_6': 'data_f'}
```

**What's the most efficient way to rotate the dict?**

The desired algorithm should take the new 'player_1' as input, and the rearrange the dict accordingly.

Example:

```
algorithm('player_4')
```

would return the following dict:

```
{'player_1': 'data_d',
 'player_2': 'data_e',
 'player_3': 'data_f'
 'player_4': 'data_a',
 'player_5': 'data_b',
 'player_6': 'data_c',
 }
```

**Edit** When iterating through a dict, I use the build in `sorted` method. Because of this, it does not matter that python dict is not sorted OOTB. The data within the dict still needs to be rearranged.

**Edit 2:**
An example of where I use the `sorted` below.

```
for player, data in sorted(players.items()):
     make_move(player, data)
     if is_interrupted(player):
         # The game was interrupted, and we need to start the next round with the player who was interrupted. 
         # This is where I need to rearrange the dict!
```

Comment: Rotation suggests a kind of **sequential** ordering in the dicts, which is not so with Python dicts, not even in Python 3.6. You can however use an `OrderedDict`.

Comment: Bear in mind that a Python dict isn't ordered.

Comment: Is it the case that either the keys or the values are actually sortable? Your example data seems to be.

Comment: show the code, including the use of `sorted()`

Comment: @Chris_Rands please see edit.

Comment: Is that the correct sort order? For example try `sorted(['player_1', 'player_2', 'player_10'])`

Comment: There is always 6 players, and the keys for the players should be player_1 to player_6.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just create sorted lists of the keys & values, then rotate the keys list, and re-build the dictionary.

```
def rotate(players, top):
    keys, vals = zip(*sorted(players.items()))
    idx = keys.index(top)
    keys = keys[idx:] + keys[:idx]
    return dict(zip(keys, vals))

# test

players = {
    'player_1': 'data_a',
    'player_2': 'data_b',
    'player_3': 'data_c',
    'player_4': 'data_d',
    'player_5': 'data_e',
    'player_6': 'data_f',
}

new_players = rotate(players, 'player_4')
for k in sorted(new_players):
    print(k, new_players[k])
```

**output**

```
player_1 data_d
player_2 data_e
player_3 data_f
player_4 data_a
player_5 data_b
player_6 data_c
```

---

If you want to modify the original `dict` object in place, you can do it this way. I print the `dict`'s id before and after the function call to verify that it's the same object.

```
def rotate(players, top):
    keys, vals = zip(*sorted(players.items()))
    idx = keys.index(top)
    keys = keys[idx:] + keys[:idx]
    players.clear()
    players.update(zip(keys, vals))

# test

players = {
    'player_1': 'data_a',
    'player_2': 'data_b',
    'player_3': 'data_c',
    'player_4': 'data_d',
    'player_5': 'data_e',
    'player_6': 'data_f',
}

print(id(players))
rotate(players, 'player_4')
print(id(players))
for k in sorted(players):
    print(k, players[k])
```

**output**

```
3072628692
3072628692
player_1 data_d
player_2 data_e
player_3 data_f
player_4 data_a
player_5 data_b
player_6 data_c
```

Comment: Awesome solution, thank you! Do you know what the big 0 notation is for the algorithm?

Comment: @Vingtoft Thanks! Using Big-O notation when discussing Python can be a little tricky because many built-in operations & methods are running at C speed, which is much faster than doing things with explicit Python loops. Eg some list method may be O(n), but unless n is huge, that list op may be faster than a much smaller explicit Python loop that's also O(n). My code is quite efficient, since it has no explicit Python loops: all of the looping is done internally by code that runs at C speed.

Comment: @Vingtoft (cont) But to answer your question, Python's TimSort is theoretically O(n log n), but it's optimized to exploit partially ordered sequences, and in that situation its complexity approaches O(n). The `list.index` method performs a linear scan to find the 1st matching item, so it's O(n). The `dict.clear` call is effectively O(1). The `dict.update(zip)` call is technically O(n), but once again, most of the work is being done at C speed, so updating a whole dict in one go like that isn't much slower than setting a couple of dict values "manually" with individual Python instructions.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying that. Nice to know that many built-in operations are running at C speed!

Answer (score 2):

Just obtain the index of the player with [`string.split()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.split):

```
# split with .split() on underscores
split_str = player.split('_')
pos = int(split_str[1]) - 1
```

Then slice the sorted list based on `pos`, and rebuild the list ordering:

```
sorted_players = sorted(players.items())
new_order = sorted_players[pos:] + sorted_players[:pos]
```

Then update the resulting list based on `sorted_players`:

```
result = []
for i, player in enumerate(new_order):
    result.append((player[0], sorted_players[i][1]))
```

The code can look like this:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

a = {'player_1': 'data_a',
     'player_2': 'data_b',
     'player_3': 'data_c',
     'player_4': 'data_d',
     'player_5': 'data_e',
     'player_6': 'data_f'}

def algorithm(players, player):
    sorted_players = sorted(players.items())

    split_str = player.split('_')
    pos = int(split_str[1]) - 1

    new_order = sorted_players[pos:] + sorted_players[:pos]

    result = [(player[0], sorted_players[i][1]) for i, player in enumerate(new_order)]

    return OrderedDict(sorted(result))

print(algorithm(a, "player_4"))
```

Which outputs:

```
OrderedDict([('player_1', 'data_d'), 
             ('player_2', 'data_e'), 
             ('player_3', 'data_f'), 
             ('player_4', 'data_a'), 
             ('player_5', 'data_b'), 
             ('player_6', 'data_c')])
```

**Note**: Wrap result with an [`OrderedDict()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) to preserve order of the players.

Answer (score 1):

Working example with a runtime of O(2n):

```
def rearrange(data, key):
    key = int(key[-1:])
    i = key - 1
    l = [data['players'][player] for player in sorted(data['players'])]
    holder = {}
    counter = 1
    for d in l[i:]:
        holder['player_'+str(counter)] = d
        counter += 1
    for d in l[:i]:
        holder['player_'+str(counter)] = d
        counter += 1
    return holder
```

Comment: Very nice solution here, didn't think of using counters.

Answer (score 1):

Split the dict up then reassemble.

```
def rotate_values(dic, key_anchor):

    ord_dic = sorted(dic.items())
    n = len(ord_dic)
    keys = []
    values = []
    new_dic = {}

    # Split dictionary into 2 lists
    for item in ord_dic:
        keys.append(item[0])
        values.append(item[1])

    # Find position of anchor and fill new dictionary with offset
    anchor_index = keys.index(key_anchor)
    for i in range(n):
        new_dic[keys[i]] = values[(i + anchor_index) % n]


    return new_dic
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution -

**Edited** answer to suit the question.
This code does not mutate the argument dictionary, but creates a new one.

```
from math import ceil

a = {
'player_1': 'data_a',
     'player_2': 'data_b',
     'player_3': 'data_c',
     'player_4': 'data_d',
     'player_5': 'data_e',
     'player_6': 'data_f'
     }


def rotate(data, playerKey):
    playerIndex = int(playerKey[-1])
    rearrangedData = {}
    for key in data:
        index = int(key[-1])
        correspondingPlayerKey = 'player_' + str((playerIndex - 1 + index - 1) % len(data.keys()) + 1)
        rearrangedData[key] = data[correspondingPlayerKey]
    return rearrangedData


print(rearrange(a, 'player_4'))
```

Prints -

```
{'player_6': 'data_c', 'player_1': 'data_d', 'player_5': 'data_b', 'player_4': 'data_a', 'player_2': 'data_e', 'player_3': 'data_f'}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, Yasser. The algorithm does not work, I get a few errors, and according to your result, player_3 now has the data of player_2. 
But thanks again for the try :-)